# Micronaut property injection to class members not working

Tags: groovy, annotations, micronaut

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in the following groovy controller.
The @Value and @Property annotations before the class members g2gApiKey2 and g2gApiKey3 are not being set.
However the @Value annotation before the g2gk parameter in the constructor *is*.

I did see that there was an issue with @Property not working in groovy but that appears to be fixed in micronaut 1.0.1, which is what we're using.

Otherwise the endpoint is set up and works fine.

```
    @Slf4j
    @Endpoint("translation")
    @Requires(property="g2g.apikey")
    class TranslationController {

        String g2gApiKey

        @Value('${g2g.apikey}')
        String g2gApiKey2

        @Property(name = "g2g.apikey")
        String g2gApiKey3

        TranslationController(@Value('${g2g.apikey}') String g2gk) {
            this.g2gApiKey = g2gk
        }

        @Write
        HttpResponse<Response> post (@Body Request req) {
            // Check for invalid request
            if (req.apiKey != g2gApiKey) return HttpResponse.unauthorized()

            Response rv = new Response()
            return HttpResponse.ok(rv)
        }
    }
```

This is the application.yml the properties are coming from:

```
g2g:
    apikey: abcd-1234
```

Comment: It is working in a service that is injected into the controller, and in a spec test.
Do I need to do something additional for an Endpoint?

Answer (score -1):

for `@Property` annotation, we need to define values in `application.properties` file.

I test this its working.

1. in `application.properties` added this line `g2g.apikey: abcd-1234`
2. in my controller reading it as

> ```
>    @Property(name ='g2g.apikey')
>     String apiKey
> ```

its working for me.

Comment: Strange, making this change did not change the behavior I'm seeing at all. Still found by Requires but only works as a constructor arg, not using Property or Value in class params.

Comment: Stranger still, as long as I use MicronautTest(propertySources = "application.yml"), both Value and Property work within a spec test.